# Variable arguments via STM32 via USB

Tags: stm32, debugging

To make printf kind of debugging possible, I planned to use variable arguments to pass to the USB device as serial device.

Code to print a test string:

```
Debug::Print("Auto toggle 2 %d %s", 12, "!");
```

With implementation:

```
void Debug::Print(const char* format, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    char buffer[256];
    vsprintf(buffer, format, args);
    Debug::Print(buffer);
    va_end(args);
}
```

I would expect:

```
 Auto toggle 2 12!
```

However, the device does not respond. When I use the OCD, at line Debug::Print, the buffer contains:

```
"Auto toggle 2 134229731 !\0§ª\232KÖ-çPä(\215õ\221º=\23   ... (continued with unreadable characters)
```

This is probably the reason the device does not respond. However, what should I use to make the buffer be filled correctly?

I tried it as a Windows console C++ program and there I get the correct output.
Initially I used a sprintf instead of vsprintf and got also a big number (lik e134229731 above). However, I did not get the additional 'rubbish'.

Comment: Looks like you have a disagreement on size of int. Your number is suspiciously close to 2^27

Comment: @glen_geek ... I made a stupid mistake in a part outside of the example that caused the problem. Now it works well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks correct. Notice the `\0` in the string:

```
"Auto toggle 2 134229731 !\0§ª\232KÖ-çPä(\215õ\221º=\23…"
                          ^^
```

The `\0` is a terminator. The debugger is displaying the rest of the (uninitialized) content in the buffer, but it's not part of the C string that will be printed.

Whatever issue you're having is being caused by something else.

Comment: You are correct, than the only (but also important) part is why it shows 134229731 instead of 12.

Comment: I accepted your answer, since the other problem is solved by a stupid mistake of me outside this example.

Comment: Now I'm curious what that mistake was.

Comment: I wanted to make a minimal example, however the function was redirected to another function which used also variable arguments, and in that function I didn't use the va_list correctly (I used va_list args without the start/send in the correct way).